# MySQL Syntax Issue with CONCAT AND LIKE in Stored Procedure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure to fetch an id. It concat's the last name with first name as "Stone, Cold" and compares with the _fullname passed which when i var_dump gives

String(13) Stone, Cold

It should give an id

```
IF NOT ISNULL(_fullname) THEN
    SET _fullname   = TRIM(_fullname);
    SET clause = CONCAT( clause , ' AND CONCAT(c.lname, ', ', c.fname) LIKE   CONCAT('%',_fullname,'%')');
END IF;
```

When i try the same query in MySQL it works perfectly fine but doesn't work in procedure. I'm sure that the problem is syntax in stored procedure.

Comment: First, tag the question correctly (MySQL or SQL Server?).  Second, use double single quotes to escape single quotes in a string constant.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thnx for replying but its still not working!!! can u please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_test`//

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`(IN `_fullname` VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
  DECLARE `clause` VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT '';
  IF NOT ISNULL(`_fullname`) THEN
    SET `_fullname` := TRIM(`_fullname`);
    SET `clause` := CONCAT(`clause`, ' AND CONCAT(`c`.`lname`, '', '', `c`.`fname`) LIKE ''', '%', `_fullname`, '%''');
  END IF;
  SELECT `clause`;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23271/1)</kbd>